# Unable to deserialise response from http request using C#

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-openai, openaiembeddings

I am currently calling a HTTP service and getting data returned. The query is the result of calling the chat completions API of Azure Open AI.

For reference

```
[webappurl]/openai/deployments/gpt35turbo/extensions/chat/completions?api-version=2023-06-01-preview
```

The reason I'm using the HTTP client approach is that I am connecting to my own datasources rather than everything. The current implementation of `Azure.AI.OpenAI` (0.7 Beta) doesn't appear to have properties for Datasources yet even though it is mentioned in the preview documentation.

Some of the response is pasted below (obtained using Fiddler) that I'm getting back from the HTTP request has the following format.

```json
data: {
    "id": "**removed**",
    "model": "gpt-35-turbo",
    "created": 1694376472,
    "object": "chat.completion.chunk",
    "choices": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "messages": [
                {
                    "delta": {
                        "role": "tool",
                        "content": "{\"citations\": [{\"content\": \"** removed ** "
                    },
                    "index": 0,
                    "end_turn": false
                }
            ],
            "finish_reason": null
        }
    ]
}

data: {
    "id": "**removed**",
    "model": "gpt-35-turbo",
    "created": 1694376472,
    "object": "chat.completion.chunk",
    "choices": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "messages": [
                {
                    "delta": {
                        "role": "assistant"
                    },
                    "index": 1,
                    "end_turn": false
                }
            ],
            "finish_reason": null
        }
    ]
}

data: {
    "id": "**removed**",
    "model": "gpt-35-turbo",
    "created": 1694376472,
    "object": "chat.completion.chunk",
    "choices": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "messages": [
                {
                    "delta": {
                        "content": ""
                    },
                    "index": 1,
                    "end_turn": false
                }
            ],
            "finish_reason": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I then have the following code to make the request and deal with the response.

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, client.BaseAddress);

var content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
request.Content = content;

var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

CompletionResponse completionResponse = new CompletionResponse();
completionResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CompletionResponse>(responseBody);
```

My class file for my model contains the following

```
public class CompletionResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("choices")]
    public List<ChatGPTChoice>? Choices
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("usage")]
    public ChatGPTUsage? Usage
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ChatGPTUsage
{
    [JsonPropertyName("prompt_tokens")]
    public int PromptTokens
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("completion_token")]
    public int CompletionTokens
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [JsonPropertyName("total_tokens")]
    public int TotalTokens
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[DebuggerDisplay("Text = {Text}")]
public class ChatGPTChoice
{
    [JsonPropertyName("text")]
    public string? Text
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

When I run the app I get to the final line above and get:

> System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'd' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: 'd' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

If I take the response and paste it into a JSON document I get the following expected a JSON object, array or literal.json. It looks to me like the response doesn't contain JSON but I don't understand what is has given me (I'm no expert).

It will probably be a daft mistake but any pointers greatly appreciate.

I've referenced this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfls6P7IaDE

Comment: If the response body really starts with `data: ` like that, then it's not valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON contains a "data" element. Your class doesn't have that.

You can create a new class like

```cs
public class CompletionResponseRoot // awful name, but whatever
{
    public CompletionResponse Data { get; set; }
}
```

Used with the existing type `CompletionResponse`, this can deserialize an object with a `Data` property that contains the rest of the data you want.

There are other properties in your classes that I don't see in the JSON, so I'm not sure what those are for.

There are also easier ways to generate the C# models for JSON. Visual Studio 2022 [has functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022) for this
If you Google "paste JSON as code" along with the name of your preferred editor you'll find other options and extensions.

You can also use a website like [Json2CSharp](https://json2csharp.com/). If that link goes out of date, just google JSON to CSharp. There are other sites. Paste in your JSON, including the outer brackets, like

```json
{
    data {
    // etc
    }
}
```

All of these will produce C# classes you can use to deserialize your JSON. They might not be perfect because they're inferred from the exact JSON you pasted, but they're usually close and often just right. In this case that produces

```cs
    public class Choice
    {
        public int index { get; set; }
        public List<Message> messages { get; set; }
        public object finish_reason { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string model { get; set; }
        public int created { get; set; }
        public string @object { get; set; }
        public List<Choice> choices { get; set; }
    }

    public class Delta
    {
        public string role { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public Delta delta { get; set; }
        public int index { get; set; }
        public bool end_turn { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }
```

You can rename the classes and delete parts you don't care about. Deserialize the JSON as type `Root` and the rest is magic.

Answer (score 0):

JSON syntax requires that all property names be quoted string. The response begins with `data:` which is not valid JSON. Everything after that, from the first `{` onwards, appears to be valid JSON that should match your DTO.

The simple solution is to skip that initial tag and deserialize the rest:

```
if (responseBody.StartsWith("data:"))
    responseBody = responseBody[5..].TrimStart();
```

Next, your DTO doesn't match the actual JSON format from the examples. You'll need to fix up the `ChatGPTChoice` class to better reflect the structure, with a class each for the `messages` array items and the `delta` record for each message. What you have at the moment will never capture the details.